# Shared login session between EasyAppointments and Bootstrap website

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, session, config

This is my first post on stackoverflow, though I have done extensive research using it along with other sources on a regular basis (including the subject I need help with here.)

To be concise, I am working on a shared session/login/register between a client's site and the EasyAppointments scheduling application. While compiling the config.php for the registration form on my client's site I received this error. I have searched everywhere, please help me understand this:

```
INSERT INTO `ea_users` (first_name, last_name, mobile_number, phone_number, address, city, state, zip_code, notes, id_roles) VALUES(testing, test, 000000000, 000000000, 123 example street, Birmington, Alabama, 00000, , )INSERT INTO `ea_user_settings` (username, password, salt, working_plan, notifications, google_sync, google_token, google_calendar, sync_past_days, sync_future_days) VALUES(TestUser, 0000000000, , , 0, , , , , )
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , 0, , , , , )' at line 2
```

Here is my config.php code (please excuse my unorthodox variables for sql1/sql2):

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', '####'); 
define('DB_USER','####'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD','####'); 

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL:  " . mysql_error()); $db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; 
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; 
$mobile_number = $_POST['mobile_number'];
$phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
$address = $_POST['address']; 
$city = $_POST['city']; 
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip_code = $_POST['zip_code'];
$noteboy = $_POST['notes'];
$privs = $_POST['id_roles']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$nick = $_POST['nick'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$salt = $_POST['salt']; 
$working_plan = $_POST['working_plan']; 
$notifications = $_POST['notifications'];
$google_sync = $_POST['google_sync'];
$google_token = $_POST['google_token']; 
$google_calendar = $_POST['google_calendar']; 
$sync_past_days = $_POST['sync_past_days'];
$sync_future_days = $_POST['sync_future_days'];

$bang = "INSERT INTO `ea_users` (first_name, last_name, mobile_number,         phone_number, address, city, state, zip_code, notes, id_roles) 
VALUES($first_name, $last_name, $mobile_number, $phone_number, $address, $city, $state, $zip_code, $noteboy, $privs)";
echo $bang;

$banger = "INSERT INTO `ea_user_settings` (username, password, salt, working_plan, notifications, google_sync, google_token, google_calendar, sync_past_days, sync_future_days)
VALUES($nick, $password, $salt, $working_plan, $notifications, $google_sync, $google_token, $google_calendar, $sync_past_days, $sync_future_days)";
echo $banger;

$result = mysql_query($bang); mysql_query($banger);
if($result) {
    echo "Successfully updated database";
} else {
    die('Error: '.mysql_error($con)); 
} 

mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you're storing phone numbers as integers, so you should be quoting all those zeroes. SQL doesn't like missing values in the `VALUES` clause, so you need to fix that to default to a format that's appropriate for your fields, such as empty string, a zero or a `NULL`. You also need to think about [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60442#60442) too to avoid errors and SQL injection vulnerabilities - using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) might be good idea if you're early on in your project, and you should definitely switch to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) at the very least.

Your check for query failure only looks at your first query - you should check both.

Anyway, here's how you might apply escaping and quoting to avoid the error you're seeing using your current approach:

```
$bang = "INSERT INTO `ea_users` (first_name, last_name, mobile_number, phone_number, address, city, state, zip_code, notes, id_roles) 
VALUES('".
    mysql_real_escape_string($first_name)."','".
    mysql_real_escape_string($last_name)."','".
    mysql_real_escape_string($mobile_number)."','".
    mysql_real_escape_string($phone_number)."','".
    mysql_real_escape_string($address)."','".
    mysql_real_escape_string($city)."','".
    mysql_real_escape_string($state)."','".
    mysql_real_escape_string($zip_code)."','".
    mysql_real_escape_string($noteboy)."','".
    mysql_real_escape_string($privs)."')";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to apply this method and let you know if it succeeds, I am kind of green when it comes to programming so I'll need all the help I can get.

Comment: okay so the page dies without inserting to database after implementation of this method, may need more assistance

Comment: As always, check your logs, check your return values, when they fail look at what is returned by things like `mysql_error()`. I just noticed that my post was truncated, so it won't work as is - I'll fix it.

Comment: I've fixed the example now.

Comment: Understood, and yes this is working now that I have notated from your change of the example. Now I am having one other issue concerning failure to update a child row but Im sure I can handle it from here, thanks alot for your help!